# A question about a property of spectral density $f(\lambda)$, i.e. $f(\lambda) \geq 0$.

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, fourier-transform, time-series

I'm reading Time Series analysis from the book *Introduction to time series and forecasting* by Peter J. Brockwell and Richard A. Davis. I'm going through the chapter of *Spectral Analysis*.

Where spectral density defined as
$$
f(\lambda) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{|h| < \infty} \exp{(-ih\lambda)} \gamma(h)
$$
Here $\{\gamma(h)\}_{|h|<\infty}$ is is auto covariance function of time series $\{X_t\}_{|t|<\infty}$.

I'm basically stuck in the proof of $f(\lambda)\geq 0 $. there is a step
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi N}\sum_{|r|<N}\sum_{|s|<N} \exp{(i\lambda(r-s))}\gamma(r-s)
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{|h|<N}\bigg(1 - \frac{|h|}{N}\bigg) \exp{(i\lambda h)}\gamma(h)
$$

How to derive the second line from the first line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is just a counting argument, but somehow I don't get the result you get in your question, so I'll leave my argument here so maybe it is useful to you or someone can correct it (or you can find a flaw in your book). The summand in the double summation only depends on $r-s$, and when $|r|,|s| < N$, the difference $r-s$ also satisfies $|r-s| < N$. So set $h \overset{def}{=} r-s$ and count the number of pairs $(r,s)$ satisfying $|r| < N$, $|s| < N$ and $r-s = h$.

One easily found such pair is $r=h$ and $s=0$. Since we want $|r-s| = h$ and $|r|$, $|s| < N$, the pairs look like this for say $h > 0$:
$$
(-N+1+h, -N+1)), \cdots, (0, -h), \cdots, (h, 0), \cdots, (N-1, N-1-h)
$$
Of course, the case $h < 0$ will have the same count, so the answer depends only on $|h|$. You see that the answers $(0,-h), (1,-h+1), \cdots, (h-1,1),(h,0)$ account for $|h|+1$ answers, and for $r < 0$ you have $N-(|h|+1)$ answers, and similarly for the answers with $s > 0$. This gives you a total of $2(N-(|h|+1)) + |h|+1 = 2N-(|h|+1)$ such pairs. So you can re-write your sum as
$$
\frac 1{2\pi N} \sum_{|r|,|s| < N} \mathrm{exp}(i\lambda(r-s)) \gamma(r-s)
$$
by putting together the terms involving $(r,s)$ with $|r|,|s| < N$ and $r-s = h$ and just put your count in front of the term, which gives
$$
\frac 1{2\pi N} \sum_{|h| < N} (2N-(h+1)) \mathrm{exp}(i\lambda h) \gamma(h)
$$
By bringing the factor $\frac 1N$ in the summation, you get
$$
\frac 1{2\pi} \sum_{|h| < N} \left( 2-\frac{|h|+1}N \right) \mathrm{exp}(i\lambda h) \gamma(h)
$$
One possible reason that I see for the discrepancy in our counts is if you're really summing over $0 \le r,s < N$ instead of $|r|,|s| < N$, because then the count becomes $N-|h|$ instead of $2N-(|h|+1)$, and you get the correct factor. That may explain your mistake (or the author's).

Hope that helps,